# Отслеживание изменения адреса страницы в расширении Chrome (html5 history api)

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension, html5-history-api

Необходимо отслеживать изменение адреса страницы (**не** изменение hash-а страницы).

Изменение происходит с помощью window.history.pushState и window.history.replaceState. 
window.onpopstate не поможет, т.к. не срабатывает при изменении адреса с помощью JavaScript.

Обычно переопределяют pushState и replaceState, всовывая в них вызов window.onpopstate, но тут это не получится из-за того, что content скрипты в расширении Chrome не имеют доступа к объекту window (читать все-же могут).

Может есть какое-то API для подобных манипуляций?

Еще есть 2 варианта: отслеживание по таймеру, что очень плохо, и навешивание обработчиков DOM 3 на добавление/удаление потомков и узлов DOM (DOM 3 Mutation events и Mutation observers), но это тоже далеко не лучший вариант в данном случае.

Comment: Боюсь отслеживания изменения как-то напрямую невозможны. Расскажите более подробно для чего вам это нужно? Что вы хотите добиться?

Comment: На англоязычном stackoverflow мне уже ответили. Мне подошел вариант с инъекцией переопределения pushState / replaceState как скрипта в документ. А отслеживание события onpopstate, оказывается, работает даже из content скрипта, хотя навешивание обработчика это, вроде как, обращение к запретному window...